# Is there a difference between :: and . when calling class methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Simple question, but one that I've been curious about...is there a functional difference between the following two commands?

```
String::class
String.class
```

They both do what I expect -- that is to say they return `Class` -- but what is the difference between using the `::` and the `.`?

I notice that on those classes that have constants defined, IRB's auto-completion will return the constants as available options when you press tab after `::` but not after `.`, but I don't know what the reason for this is...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `.` operator basically says "send this message to the object". In your example it is calling that particular member. The `::` operator "drills down" to the scope defined to the left of the operator, and then calls the member defined on the right side of operator.

When you use `::` you have to be referencing members that are defined. When using `.` you are simply sending a message to the object. Because that message could be anything, auto-completion does not work for `.` while it does for `::`.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, auto-completion does work for `.`.  The completion options are found by calling `#methods` on the object.  You can see this for yourself by overriding `Object.methods`:

```
>> def Object.methods; ["foo", "bar"]; end
=> nil
>> Object.[TAB]
Object.foo  Object.bar
>> Object.
```

Note that this only works when the expression to the left of the `.` is a literal.  Otherwise, getting the object to call `#methods` on would involve evaluating the left-hand side, which could have side-effects.  You can see this for yourself as well:

```
[continuing from above...]
>> def Object.baz; Object; end
=> nil
>> Object.baz.[TAB]
Display all 1022 possibilities? (y or n)
```

We add a method `#baz` to `Object` which returns `Object` itself.  Then we auto-complete to get the methods we can call on `Object.baz`.  If IRB called `Object.baz.methods`, it would get the same thing as `Object.methods`.  Instead, IRB has 1022 suggestions.  I'm not sure where they come from, but it's clearly a generic list which isn't actually based on context.

The `::` operator is (also) used for getting a module's constants, while `.` is not.  That's why `HTTP` will show up in the completion for `Net::`, but not for `Net.`.  `Net.HTTP` isn't correct, but `Net::HTTP` is.