# . vs :: (dot vs. double-colon) for calling a method

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby from the [Poignant Guide to Ruby](http://www.rubyinside.com/media/poignant-guide.pdf) and in some of the code examples, I came across uses of the double colon and dot that seem to be used for the same purpose:

```
File::open( 'idea-' + idea_name + '.txt', 'w' ) do |f|
   f << idea
end
```

In the above code, the double colon is being used to access the `open` method of the `File` class. However, I later came across code that used a dot for the same purpose:

```
require 'wordlist'
# Print each idea out with the words fixed
Dir['idea-*.txt'].each do |file_name|
   idea = File.read( file_name )
   code_words.each do |real, code| 
     idea.gsub!( code, real )
   end
puts idea
end
```

This time, a dot is being used to access the `read` method of the `File` class. What is the difference between:

```
File.read()
```

and

```
File::open()
```

Comment: I really don't think this is a duplicate of that. Nowhere in that question or its answers is the use of `::` with regard to singleton methods discussed.

Comment: I agree. I saw that other question before I opened this one. However, the answer to my question was not explicitly given. The other question discusses the use only of the :: operator. Maybe its hints at the use use of the dot operator in a subtle way, but when you are new to something, you need the answer in a very distinct form. And like I stated, I am new to ruby.

Comment: The duplicates offered by the moderator are not helpful. However there is a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134/is-there-a-difference-between-and-when-calling-class-methods-in-ruby

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's the [*scope resolution operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#Ruby).

An example from Wikipedia:

```
module Example
  Version = 1.0

  class << self # We are accessing the module's singleton class
    def hello(who = "world")
       "Hello #{who}"
    end
  end
end #/Example

Example::hello # => "Hello world"
Example.hello "hacker" # => "Hello hacker"

Example::Version # => 1.0
Example.Version # NoMethodError

# This illustrates the difference between the message (.) operator and the scope
# operator in Ruby (::).
# We can use both ::hello and .hello, because hello is a part of Example's scope
# and because Example responds to the message hello.
#
# We can't do the same with ::Version and .Version, because Version is within the
# scope of Example, but Example can't respond to the message Version, since there
# is no method to respond with.
```

Comment: This does not answer the question: "what is the difference between `File.read()` and `File::open()`?". And why can both be used to call a method? When would we choose one over the other?

Comment: There is NO difference between :: and . when calling class (static) methods in functionality. But you can use :: to access constants and other namespaced things, for which you can't use dot. I personally use dot all the time, but my colleague use :: for calling static methods. Maybe it is somewhat aesthetically nicer when you call namespaced thing, like Foo::Bar::open (instead of Foo::Bar.open), but it works the same both ways. Performance is the same too. P.S. Here is nice discussion on this topic: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/107527

Comment: This example lacks a version: `Example::hello("hacker")` I feel like the example given implies this is not possible, though the text states it is.