# Accessing module methods from a class in that module?

Tags: ruby, module

Under Ruby 2.0, what is the correct way to access a module method from a class in that module?

For instance, if I have

```
module Foo
    class Foo
        def do_something
            Foo::module_method
        end
    end

    def self.module_method
        puts 'How do I call this?'
    end
end
```

I get,

> ./so-module.rb:7:in `do_something': undefined method`module_method'
>   for Foo::Foo:Class (NoMethodError)    from ./so-module.rb:16:in `'

What is the correct way to define the module method so I can access it from class `Foo`?

Comment: Are you sure that’s the error you’re getting? I get “NoMethodError: undefined method `module_method' for Foo:Module”.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, you're right, something was lost in translation from my actual code to simplifying it down to an example. Let me see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Ah ok, I also had a problem with the class name being the same as the module name and that was causing weird stuff to happen, so I've corrected that.

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect the changes?

Comment: I actually don't get the exact same error even with a changed script, but I will update it to reflect more closely my original problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the method on the module’s singleton class:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def do_something
      Foo.module_method
    end
  end

  def self.module_method
    'Success!'
  end
end

Foo::Bar.new.do_something  #=> "Success!"
```

Comment: This also works with `Foo::module_method`. What's the difference, if any?

Comment: See [. vs :: (dot vs. double-colon) for calling a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043450/vs-dot-vs-double-colon-for-calling-a-method).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at following code:

```
module Foo
    class Bar
        include Foo
        def do_something
            module_method
        end
    end
    def module_method
        puts 'How do I call this?'
    end
end

b = Foo::Bar.new
b.do_something
```

result:

```
How do I call this?
```

You can even try adding following code:

```
b1 = Foo::Bar::Bar.new
b1.do_something
```

It's tricky and has same result:

```
How do I call this?
```