# What is the difference between accessing class methods via "." or "::"?

Tags: ruby, class-method

Given a Ruby class with a static method like

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

I always accessed the method via

```
Foo.bar
```

However, I just noticed that you can also do

```
Foo::bar
```

Why is that? Is there a semantic difference? My initial idea was that it's a matter of treating `Foo` as a class object (in which case the first version seems plausible) vs. treating it as a "namespace" like a module, in which case the second version makes sense.

Comment: How many answers you want ? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+%22.%22+%22%3A%3A%22 :-)

Comment: Argh, why didn't I find them... the Google-fu is weak with me. However, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134/is-there-a-difference-between-and-when-calling-class-methods-in-ruby is actually a better match for a "duplicate".

Comment: I don't have access to vote for close.. You can mark it now dup with the one you just linked.. :) I am withdrawing mine